# Is there a way to express "would be"?

Tags: grammar

For example, if I wanted to say:

"I thought it would be difficult." (Didn't attempt it, thought it seemed difficult)

Is there a way to translate this directly to japanese or am I limited to:

「難しいと思った」(Attempted it and thought it was difficult)?

Comment: The modal "would" has a myriad of different grammatical functions and usages in English. So maybe it _would_ make more sense to restrict the question title to the specifc context you've given?

Comment: @EddieKal True.. maybe "I thought it *seemed* difficult" would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we'd normally translate it as:

> 難しい**だろう**と思った。 I thought it would be difficult.

Compare:

> 難しいと思った。 I thought it was difficult.
> 難しいと思う。 I think it is difficult.
> 難しいだろうと思う。 I think it will be difficult.

> "I thought it seemed difficult."

We'd usually translate it as 「難し**そうだ**と思った。」 Compare:

> 難しそうだ。 It seems difficult.
> 難しそうだと思う。 I think it seems difficult.

Comment: @62626368616e 「意味ある」って？